# How to insert an array of values into a particular column and fetch it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

So, I want to insert an entire array of values into a particular column and I don't know exactly what to do. Everything I have tried gives me the "Array to string conversion" error.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function processInternationaTransfer(Request $request)
    {
    $international_info = Validator::make($request->all(), 
    [
        'beneficiary_name' => 'required',
        'beneficiary_acc_num' => 'required|numeric',
        'beneficiary_bank' => 'required',
        'beneficiary_swiftcode' => 'required',
        'routing_transit_no' => 'required|numeric',
        'currency' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required|numeric',
        'note' => 'required',
    ]
    );

        if($international_info->fails())
        {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$international_info->errors()->all()]);
        }
        $info = $international_info->validated();
        $balance = $info['currency'].'_balance';
        if(user_details()->$balance < InternationalAmount($info['amount']))
        {
            return response()->json(['insufficient_amount'=>'Insufficient Amount']);
        }
        else
        {
            TransactionLog::create([
                'username' => user()->username,
                'type' => 'Exchange',
                'cred_deb' => 'Debit',
                'time'=> Carbon::now('Africa/Lagos')->format('l, d F, Y g:i A'),
                'status' => 2,
                'amount'=>InternationalAmount($info['amount']),
                'currency'=>$info['currency'],
                'reason' => $info['note'],
                'inter_details' => $info,
                'transaction_id' => rand(100000000, 999999999),
            ]);
            return response()->json(['success'=>'Transaction Processed, Awaiting Confirmation']);
        }

    }
```

How do I insert that array of values into the inter_details column?

I tried inserting it as it is above, and it gives me "array to string conversion" error.
I want to be able to fetch it after inserting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure that the `inter_details` can accept many characters the best way to do that is to use the `json()` in migrations

```
$table->json('inter_details'); //it will create a longText column in database so that it can accept many characters.
```

then add a casts to the `TransactionLogs` Model

```
protected $casts = [
   'inter_details' => 'array',
]
```

in this way you can access the inter_details as  an array when you fetch it from the database you don't need to use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`. if you want to `casts` it in other types there are many more from the documentation

[Eloquent: Mutators & Casting - Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Answer (score 0):

To insert an array of values into a particular column, you need to use the DB facade's insert method. The insert method takes an array of values as its first argument and the table name as its second argument.

For example, if you want to insert an array of values into the inter_details column, you can do the following:

```
$inter_details = [
    'beneficiary_name' => 'John Doe',
    'beneficiary_acc_num' => '12345678',
    'beneficiary_bank' => 'Bank of America',
    'beneficiary_swiftcode' => 'ABC123',
    'routing_transit_no' => '123456789',
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'amount' => '1000',
    'note' => 'This is a test transaction',
];

DB::table('transaction_logs')->insert([
    'inter_details' => json_encode($inter_details),
]);
```

The json_encode() function is used to convert the array into a JSON string, which can then be stored in the database.

To fetch the array of values from the database, you can use the DB facade's select method. For example:

```
$inter_details = DB::table('transaction_logs')->select('inter_details')->get();

$inter_details = json_decode($inter_details, true);
```

The json_decode() function is used to convert the JSON string back into an array. The second argument of the function is set to true, which tells the function to return an associative array instead of an object.

Now you have the array of values stored in the $inter_details variable, which you can use as you wish.